# Gems/packages/APIs for generating virtual webcam to stream a video file to

Tags: webcam

Goal: Create a testing framework for using a file that will mimic folks streaming their webcam video to our server

Thoughts so far: The two thoughts I'm trying to locate is to generate my own virtual webcam package or finding a way to inject a video file as a livestream to the webcam.

Anyone got any suggestions?  I'm trying to find options for Ruby, C#, or Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only *easy* solution I found for this in the end is only in the ChromeDriver.  You can pass in the following options to ChromeDriver when launched:

```
--use-file-for-fake-video-capture=<filename>
--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture=<filename>
--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream
--use-fake-device-for-media-stream
```

This will let you send in an audio & a video stream in as the default fake audio/video devices for the browser.